# How I find $\beta$ for to do this function continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits

My function is: $f(x) = x^3 $ if $0\leq x \leq 1 $ or $x^2-\beta x+ \beta$ if $1 < x \leq 2$ .

**My answer:**

For this function to be continuous the $\lim_{x\to1^+} x^2 - \beta x + \beta = \lim_{x\to1^-} x^3$, when a apply the limit I have this:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1^+} x^2 - \beta x + \beta = 1 - \beta +\beta\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1^-} x^3 = 1
\end{align}

I want a value for $\beta$ but he is canceling there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong. Your function is continuous for all $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

Now, if you're interested in which $\beta$, if any, that will make $f$ differentiable on $(0,1)$, then you just repeat the analysis but with the difference ratio.

Note:
$$
\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{(1+h)^2-\beta(1+h)+\beta-1}{h}=\lim_{h\downarrow 0}(2+h-\beta)=2-\beta,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{h\uparrow 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\uparrow 0}\frac{(1+h)^3-1}{h}=3.
$$
What can $\beta$ be? In the end, your $f$ should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: But I want a value for $\beta$, How I get this?? Because I can't isolate him.

Comment: @JulianaRodrigues Any $\beta$ works. Once you've checked that your math is sound, be confident in the answer.

Comment: Since any real number value of $\beta$ works, and since you want a specific value of $\beta$, you are free to pick any real number value that you like. Pick a number, any number. I, myself, like $\beta = 42$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, because I want to satisfy the conditions of the Mean value theorem. Now I will verify the others conditions.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ is called continuous in $x=1$ if $\lim\limits_{x\uparrow1}f(x)=\lim\limits_{\downarrow1}f(x)=f(1)$. By your definition of $f$, it follows easily that $f(1)=1^3=\lim\limits_{x\uparrow1}f(x)$ and that for all $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$, it follows that $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow1}f(x)=1$, so $f$ is continuous in $x=1$ for all values of $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks! Because I need to apply  the Mean value theorem in one range [0,2] , so for the first condition of the theorem I can say that this function is continuous for all values of $\beta$?

Comment: Yes you can very well say that but in order to use the mean value theorem, you should show that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,2)$ as well. Now, try to show with the definition above that the function is only differentiable for a certain value of $\beta$.